# Facebook Graph API doesn't display birthday

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an Android app where I need access to all the birthdays of my facebooks friends. But somehow I only get the birthdays of very few people.

Could it be that the new Facebook Timeline causes this bug? Because if I go to Graph API Explorer I don't see them either although almost every friend of mine has set his birthday visible. 
I also noticed that I was able to see the birthdays of my friends who still have the old facebook without the timeline.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the correct [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)s for accessing friends' birthdays?

Comment: I hope so. These are the permissions I use: 

String[] permissions = { "offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins",
    "photo_upload","friends_birthday","friends_location", "friends_hometown", "email", "friends_status"};

It does work for some friends that don't use the timeline. Does the timeline need different permissions?

Comment: Are you sure that you friends given your to access their birthday , Also check whether they have birthday field..

Comment: Also use try catch block while populating birthday list , coz , if there is an empty field it will exception will be thrown and rest part might be skipped.. So take a look at that..

Answer (score 5):

For birthday following are the two permissions

```
friends_birthday,user_birthday
```

The behavior is same for old wall and Timeline users. Double check you are taking the above permissions using following tool.

[Accesstoken Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=user_token)

and if permissions are there check friends birthday using following tool

[Graph Api tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends?fields=birthday,name)

PS: User can apply privacy on its year but not on its complete birthday. 
For some people birthday will not show up using graph api because they have opted out of Facebook applications using Facebook setting..

Comment: Indeed; users can also opt out of making their birthday available to apps that their friend are using, without needing to block the app or remove platform entirely

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. It was indeed this privacy option who denied the access: http://i.imgur.com/OMFml.jpg It seems like birthday is disabled by default. :/